# Hyper-V memory allocation

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I currently have a Win 2008r2 server with 132 GB of Ram installed.  I also have a hyper-v machine currently running. I can not increase the ram past 52000mb under static. I currently have memory buffer set 20% and the memory weight set for middle. There will be no other virtual machines added to this server. My question, why can't the virtual machine start and use more ram 52000mb?

more specifics:

- win 2008 r2 stanadard (physical host)
- win 2008 r2 standard (virtual)

Comment: Do you hit the limit at 52001 MB?  I'd suspect your actual limit is actually 64GB.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee405267(v=ws.10).aspx.  I wouldn't necessarily expect the 20% memory buffer to reduce that number, but knocking 20% off of 64GB puts you near your listed limit.  You could experiment removing that buffer, and see if it lets you go up to 64GB.

Answer (score 0):

Memory limit for Win 2008 R2 Standard is 32GB so anything allocated beyond that will not be used by the server.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_server_2008_r2